# Verilog: 1-Bit Full Adder will not run on FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga, spartan

Taking baby steps with Verilog and Xilinx ISE Webpack, flashing this to a Mimas V2 Spartan 6 gives no output when any switches are pressed, can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
module OneBitFullAdder(
input wire ci,
input wire a,
input wire b,
output wire sum,
output wire co
 );

assign co = (a&b)|(ci&(a^b));
assign sum = (a^b^ci);

endmodule
```

Here are my constraints:

```
NET "b" PULLDOWN;
NET "a" PULLDOWN;
NET "ci" PULLDOWN;

NET "sum" LOC = T18;
NET "b" LOC = L18;
NET "a" LOC = M18;
NET "ci" LOC = M16;
NET "co" LOC = T17;
```

And here's the board schematic for port allocation:

https://docs.numato.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/mimasv2-dipswitch.png

It works in simulation, and in practise I found the LEDs output the correct logic if I set any combination of inputs to pull-up, but pressing switches has no effect. I've tried allocating different switches.

If I've missed out some information that will help, let me know, serious beginner here (in both Verilog and FPGA).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should be using pullups instead of pulldowns on those inputs. If you look at the schematics the signals are grounded when you press the buttons. So the signal is pulled down to a logical 0 when the button isn't pressed and grounded to a logical 0 when it is pressed.

Comment: I am also feeling the same. What is the reason for using pulldowns at inputs @GJFT?

Comment: This did indeed solve the problem. 

My thinking was along the lines of "pulldown = initialise as zero" which would then go high on a switch press, but I can now see why that's wrong.

Thanks for taking the time to solve my newbie problem!